# Create (upload) picture on Buddy platform

Tags: javascript, image, upload, sdk, buddy.com

I'm trying to [upload a picture](https://buddyplatform.com/docs/Create%20Picture) with Buddy (backend as a service).

I am using Buddy JS SDK and I have an error:

This is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

Buddy.init("api_key", "api-id");

 Buddy.post("/pictures", {data : "data:image/vnd.microsoft.icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAQAAEABAAoAQAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEABAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZswzAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAERABEREAAAAREAEREQAAABEQEQABEAAAAAARAAEQAAAAABEAARAAAAAAEQABEAAAAAARAAEQAAAAABEAARAAAAAAEQABEAAAAAARAAEQAAAAABEAARAAAAAAEQABEAAAAAABEREAAAAAAAEREQAAAAAAAAAAAAD//wAAxg8AAMYPAADE5wAA/OcAAPznAAD85wAA/OcAAPznAAD85wAA/OcAAPznAAD85wAA/g8AAP4PAAD//wAA"
  },  function(err, docs) {
    if (err) console.log("err is" +err);
    console.log("picture is" +docs);
});   
});
```

This is the error

```
{"status": 400,
 "error": "ParameterIncorrectFormat",
 "errorNumber": 515,
"message": "Can not convert 'data:image/vnd.microsoft.icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAQAAEABAAoAQAAFgAAACgAAAAQAA…YPAADE5wAA/OcAAPznAAD85wAA/OcAAPznAAD85wAA/OcAAPznAAD85wAA/g8AAP4PAAD//wAA' to HttpPostedFileBase.",
"request_id": "53a99fed426ac909a00b221a",
"success": false 
}  :
```

I have tried with

```
"base64,AAABAAEAEBAQAAEABAAoAQAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEABAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZswzAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAERABEREAAAAREAEREQAAABEQEQABEAAAAAARAAEQAAAAABEAARAAAAAAEQABEAAAAAARAAEQAAAAABEAARAAAAAAEQABEAAAAAARAAEQAAAAABEAARAAAAAAEQABEAAAAAABEREAAAAAAAEREQAAAAAAAAAAAAD//wAAxg8AAMYPAADE5wAA/OcAAPznAAD85wAA/OcAAPznAAD85wAA/OcAAPznAAD85wAA/g8AAP4PAAD//wAA"
```

and with

```
"AAABAAEAEBAQAAEABAAoAQAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEABAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZswzAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAERABEREAAAAREAEREQAAABEQEQABEAAAAAARAAEQAAAAABEAARAAAAAAEQABEAAAAAARAAEQAAAAABEAARAAAAAAEQABEAAAAAARAAEQAAAAABEAARAAAAAAEQABEAAAAAABEREAAAAAAAEREQAAAAAAAAAAAAD//wAAxg8AAMYPAADE5wAA/OcAAPznAAD85wAA/OcAAPznAAD85wAA/OcAAPznAAD85wAA/g8AAP4PAAD//wAA"
```

and I have always this error.

I have tested with google image and service http://base64image.org/ with this

pictureImages intégrées 1

```
raw:"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"
```

and I've got this error too.

How to make the image upload work?

Answer (score 1):

For the value of the data parameter, you should pass a JavaScript File or Blob object.  Here is a short sample using jQuery and the SDK (https://github.com/BuddyPlatform/Buddy-JS-SDK):

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
<input id="uploadButton" type="button" value="Upload" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#uploadButton").click(function () {
            var fileInput = $("#file")[0];

            // get a key and id from http://buddyplatform.com
            Buddy.init("api_key", "api-id");

            Buddy.loginUser("testuser", "testpassword");

            Buddy.post("/pictures", {
                data: fileInput.files[0]
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you need to send up a base64 string explicitly, you will need to make a multi-part MIME POST request, which is what the Buddy SDK is doing on your behalf.  If you look into the SDK itself, the code there can guide you.

Comment: By the way, it'd be great to start tagging Buddy Platform questions with [tag:buddy.com].

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261582/new-tag-request-buddy-com Tag request proposed